# Using Select-String does not work when trying to match with an "if" statement

Tags: powershell

I have tried a number of different things, but just cant seem to get this to work. I am new to `Select-String`, and it seems pretty complicated.

I have a text file with a list of error codes that I hope to match with an `if ($errorcode -match $retrieveError)`, but the `$retrieveError` that I am using has a `Select-String` that returns a much larger string than what I am looking for. For example:

The string I am looking for is: *An error occurred stopping transcription*

The string the Select-String returns is: *<![LOG[Stop-Transcript : An error occurred stopping transcription: The host is not currently transcribing.]LOG]!><time="17:02:46.072+300" date="12-10-2021" component="RunPowerShellScript" context="" type="3" thread="8436" file="main.cpp:76">' at offset 13. [x-y] range in reverse order.*

This is my script:

```
####This code is used for copying failed OS Upgrade log files to a destination that can be read by Desktop###

#Get Computer names from list
$computers = Get-Content -Path "\\@path1\Machines with Win10 Errors.txt"

#Get Error codes from list 
$errorcodes = Get-Content -Path "\\@path2\Win10 Install Error List.txt"

#If error unknown, move to Unknown folder
#$moveunknown = Move-Item -Path $logfiledest\"$errorcode"\$computer.txt

#Define computers array and execute actions for each
ForEach($computer in $computers){

    #Define Log File Destination
    $logfiledest = "\\@path3\$computer.txt"
    #Copy log file to $logfiledest and rename with computer name
    Copy-Item -Path C:\Windows\ccm\Logs\smsts.log -Destination $logfiledest

    #Define error codes array and execute actions for each
    ForEach($errorcode in $errorcodes){

        #Read log files in $logfiledest to match defined log strings in $errorcodes txt file
        $retrieveError = Select-String -Path $logfiledest -SimpleMatch $errorcode -Raw
   ## $retrieveError = Select-String -Path \\$computer\C$\Windows\ccm\Logs\smsts.log -Pattern "$errorcode"

    if ($errorcode -match $retrieveError) {  #not working

        #Rename log files to include error code
        Rename-Item -Path $logfiledest -NewName $computer+"$errorcode".txt  #working
        #Move renamed log files into matching folders
        Move-Item -Path $logfiledest"+$errorcode.txt"  #working
       

    }else {
        
        Write-Host "nada"
    }

}
}
```

Comment: Did you read the last two comments from AdminOfThings from your last question? His last comment is key to understand how you should approach the problem.

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon Definitely trying it now, but it seemed like I needed to post the whole script because I don't think I gave enough information

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem. You search for an error code, `Select-String` returns a string that contains said error code. Which part is not working?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen The select-string returns the entire line, not just what I am looking for.

Comment: But if you're looking for `-SimpleMatch $errorcode` and `Select-String` returns _anything_ then you already know that `$errorcode` was found - so what additional information are you hoping to learn? FWIW you can "fix" it by swapping the arguments so the if condition becomes `$retrieveError -match ([regex]::Escape($errorcode))` - but I still don't understand the point.

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen I need to return just the error code, because I am renaming the files with that specific error code, then moving them into specific folders. There will be multiple error codes in the .txt file. The "extra" information that is returned in the string can't work because there is dates and times.

Comment: But _you already know which error code it is_ - it's stored `$errorCode`, so just output `$errorCode` whenever `Select-String` returns _anything_ :)

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon although it wasn't exactly, it did help in my situation. Answering question above.

Answer (score 0):

`(Select-String -Path $logfiledest -SimpleMatch $errorcode).Pattern`
Is the answer...finally